# Android web page not updating after changing styles in server

Tags: java, android, webview

Android web page not updating after changing styles.But it works in browser.How can I do the same in webview.

My **webview config** is

```
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 5 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 5MB
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT ); // load online by default
```

Comment: Might be displayinig from cache,
clear it and try again

Answer (score 1):

In order to disable the cache use this setting.

`mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);`